# MYSQL Delete FIRST duplicates from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 511 duplicates in my table, I need to delete these, but not the originals. Therefore I want to delete every second occurrence of every duplicate.

How can I do this?

TABLE:

```
code  /   status  /   time
E3F4FF928A  /  0 /
07D95444BB  /  0 /  
07D95444BB /   0 / 
40006C128F  / 0  / 1315293012
2B45790E52   /  0  /
40006C128F  / 0  / 1315293012
```

Comment: please post your table definition.

Comment: Are they exact duplicates, or do you have a unique key somewhere in there?

Comment: A true duplicate is the exact copy of the original. Do you really have duplicates, or do you have rows where lots of the data is identical, but something like the auto inc column or created date are different?

Comment: you need to provide the table schema (columns) as well as some sample data

Comment: deleted          deleted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add a unique index to the table on the column that should be unique, and ignore errors

```
alter ignore table X add unique index (column_a)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Does not address *I want to delete every second occurrence of every duplicate.*

Comment: yeah this does not accomplish the desired result.

Comment: be more specific .. you have a b a b c b a  .. Do you want a b c  or do you want a b c b a ?

Comment: Actually, the MySql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) specifies: `only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted`

Comment: +1, I like this answer, you may need a compound index though, just add extra fields to the index `unique index (col1, col2, col3)`.

Comment: well how can i do it deleting the first occurrence?

Comment: if it's really a duplicate, it doesn't matter.. Is it really a duplicate, or is only some of the information the same? You might want to post some sample data and your table def.

Answer (score 7):

Just run into this problem today (no unique key in the table).

I solved it like this

```
DELETE FROM table where code=x and status=y and time=z LIMIT 1;
```

This will delete the first 1 row for the given criteria (if you have n duplicates, put n-1 to keep only one).

Comment: it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t2 FROM table1 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON 
      (t1.somefield = t2.somefield 
   AND t1.otherfield = t2.otherfield   /*add more fields if need be */
   AND t2.id > t1.id)
LEFT JOIN table1 t3 ON 
      (t1.somefield = t3.somefield 
   AND t1.otherfield = t3.otherfield   /*add more fields if need be */
   AND t3.id > t2.id) 
WHERE (t3.id IS NULL)  
ORDER BY t2.id ASC
```

This should only delete the 2nd duplicate and leave 3rd and beyond duplicates alone.

If you want something less esoteric, and you have a timestamp column, perhaps you want to do

```
DELETE t2 FROM table1 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON 
      (t1.somefield = t2.somefield 
   AND t1.otherfield = t2.otherfield   /*add more fields if need be */
   AND t2.`timestamp` > t1.`timestamp`)
WHERE (1=1)        /*In some mode(s) MySQL requires a where clause with delete*/
ORDER BY t2.id ASC
```